# Invoking a third party payment url from angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I had to invoke a third party payment url from angular 8 application. This is how am doing that.

```
redirectToPayment(url){
    this.savePayment();
    if (url) {
      window.location.href = url;
    }
   }
```

I had never done this before. Is this secured way of doing this ?.
Is there any other strict browser mode available ?

Answer (score 0):

Navigating to a different site is outside your application scope (it's done by the browser, you just give out the command to it) See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location. Your current solution is alright.

What do you whish to "secure"?

- if you application code is compromised, the user can be redirected to any url the attacker wants.
- if you want to securely transit the authentication/authorization credentials of your users, you might want to look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0